# How do i expand menu after clicking top left icon?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

How do i implement the functionality on top left corner icon, like by clicking it menu should become active. I have attached the codepen link for html,css and js code. Codepen link: https://codepen.io/RSH87/pen/rmgYbo. Just needed help in adding the javascript file in react app.I have also attached my screenshot. This is my react code.

```js
/*App.js file */

import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="menu-icon">
        
    <span className="menu-icon__line menu-icon__line-left"></span>
    <span className="menu-icon__line"></span>
    <span className="menu-icon__line menu-icon__line-right"></span>
</div>

<div className="nav">

    <div className="nav__content">
        <ul className="nav__list">
            <li className="nav__list-item">Home</li>
            <li className="nav__list-item">About</li>
            <li className="nav__list-item">Projects</li>
            <li className="nav__list-item">Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div className="site-content">
    <h1 className="site-content__headline">Polar S2</h1>
</div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


/*index.js file*/

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))

reportWebVitals();
```

```html
<!--index.html file--->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

[My react app output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YgyN.png)

[Output i want after clicking top left corner icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UveWf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `useEffect` for executing a function after the DOM mounted.

**App.js**

```jsx
import {useEffect} from "react";

function App() {

  useEffect(() => {

    // You can use that script from the Codepen.

  },[]);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="menu-icon">
       ..... blah ... blah
  );
}
```

Read: https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useeffect.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use onClick function to toggle class, `<div className="menu-icon" onClick={toggleNav}>` like following:

https://codepen.io/amandeep1852/pen/ZEvVBdd